# Google Tag fires but not logged in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I had set up my Google Tag to track clicks on spans with certain IDs, the events are firing according to WASP extension, but they are not showing up in my Google Analytics account.

Here is my trigger:

[image: trigger]

My Tag:

[image: tag]

WASP in action:

[image: wasp1]
[image: wasp2]

GA displays pageview only:

[image: ga]

Code is installed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this seems pretty obvious, but in Real Time you should be on the Events tab, and it seems you are looking in the Content tab. Events are never displayed there.

Comment: Oh god, that was easy. Thank you so much. I now see my click events, but not the simple pageviews for some reason, lol

Answer (score 0):

While the configuration looks to be correct, remember that events won't show up in your standard reports until the data is processed, which takes about 24 hours. As long as the hit is showing up in your Real-Time reports, then you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post **full HTTP request**? For instance from **Charles Web Debugging Proxy** of **Live HTTP Headers** extension or anything simillar.

What you post seems to be correct as @nyuen says!